# how to parse repeated elements with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm new to Nokogiri, so how do I parse the "data" and it's text, as well as 
the "name" from the "method" in the following xml:

```
<get_escalators_response status="200" status_text="OK">
<escalator id="6181e65d-8ba0-4937-9c44-8f2b10b0def7">
 <name>Team alert</name>
 <comment/>
 <in_use>1</in_use>
 <condition>
   Threat level at least
   <data>
     High
     <name>level</name>
   </data>
 </condition>
 <event>
   Task run status changed
   <data>
     Done
     <name>status</name>
   </data>
 </event>
 <method>
   Email
   <data>
     team@example.org
     <name>to_address</name>
   </data>
   <data>
     admin@example.org
     <name>from_address</name>
   </data>
   <data>
     0
     <name>notice</name>
   </data>
 </method>
</escalator>
...
</get_escalators_response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to do this, here's one:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML("your_xml_document")
doc.search("data").each do |data|
  name = data.search("name").remove # remove the name element from data element
  name_text = name.text
  data_text = data.text
  # do stuff with text
end
```

You can search for specific nested elements like this:

```
doc.search("method > data").each do |data|
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I just want to grab name/data from "method" and not "condition" or "event" ?

Comment: Nevermind, doc.search("method/data").each do |data| ... seems to work. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Assigning your XML to a variable called `xml`, I'd go about it like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
pp doc.search('//method/data').map{ |n| n.text.scan(/\S+/) }
```

Notice this is returning an array of arrays. It'd be easy to coerce the data into strings or hashes.

```
# >> [["team@example.org", "to_address"],
# >>  ["admin@example.org", "from_address"],
# >>  ["0", "notice"]]
```